# Laravel: how to make hasMany relation for rows with highest value and using groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my Laravel project I have two models: **Offer** and **OfferPromotion**.

**OfferPromotion Table Example:**
[Database table schema of offer_promotions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuq8v.png)

In **Offer** model I want to make **hasMany relation** called **"activePromotions"**. It must group promotions by type and select these with highest expiration date (last inserted record). In case presented in the image above I want to get:
Type highlight to 2020-02-25
Type home to 2020-04-11
Code below turned out to be incorrect, cause it returns only promotions for first offer and rest is empty. I think it's reason of using groupBy in wrong way.

```
class Offer extends Model{
    (...)
    public function activePromotions(){
         return $this->hasMany(OfferPromotion::class)
            ->whereDate('expires_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->select(\DB::raw(\DB::getTablePrefix().'offer_promotions.*, 
                max('.\DB::getTablePrefix().'offer_promotions.expires_at) 
                as expires_at')
             )
            ->orderBy('expires_at', 'ASC') //display promotions in expiration order
            ->groupBy('type');
    }
}
```

In my Controller i use **"with" statement**:

```
$offers = Offer::MyOffers( $loggedUser->id )
                ->with(['files', 'activePromotions', 'owner' => function($query){ $query->with('seller');}])
                ->latest()
                ->paginate(10);
```

I searched and tried many solutions, but none of them works. I tried **whereIn with subquery**, **joins** etc. but nothing works.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally made it**
Solution:

```
public function activePromotions(){
        return $this->hasMany(OfferPromotion::class)
            ->select('offer_promotions.*')
            ->leftJoin('offer_promotions as promotions2', function($join){
                return $join->on('offer_promotions.offer_id', '=', 'promotions2.offer_id')
                    ->on('offer_promotions.type', 'promotions2.type')
                    ->on('offer_promotions.expires_at', '<', 'promotions2.expires_at');
            })
            ->whereNull('promotions2.expires_at')
            ->where('offer_promotions.expires_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone.